# Show an HTML DIV at random

Tags: javascript, html

It's probably really simple but I can not get this code to work. What I would like to do is have 3 DIVs which is hidden unless it has been randomly chosen by the JavaScript code. I have looked at this post but I still couldn't figure it out.

```
<html onload="load()">   
<body>
<div class="light-grey">

<div id="q1">
div 1
</div>
<div id="q2">
div 2
</div>
<div id="q3">
div 3
</div>

</div>
</body>
<script>

function load(){
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1   //numbers 1 - 3
     if (randomNumber == 1) {
          document.getElementById("q1").style.display = "inline";
          document.getElementById("q2").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("q3").style.display = "none";
     }
     if (randomNumber == 2) {
          document.getElementById("q1").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("q2").style.display = "inline";
          document.getElementById("q3").style.display = "none";
     }
     if (randomNumber == 3) {
          document.getElementById("q1").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("q2").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("q3").style.display = "inline";
     }

}
</script>
</html>
```

Each time I've tried it shows all 3 DIVs at the same time. It's probably something really obvious since I am new at JavaScript. If you have any queries comment below. Thanks in advance.

Comment: onload should be on the body, not html tag. Better yet addEventListener...

Comment: Oh man, something so simple, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onload atribute was in the wrong tag it was needed on body instead of html

```js
function load() {
        const randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3); //numbers 1 - 3
        console.log(randomNumber);

        for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            const id = "q" + i;
            if (randomNumber === i) {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = "inline";
            } else {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="load()">
<div class="light-grey">
    <div id="q1">
        div 1
    </div>
    <div id="q2">
        div 2
    </div>
    <div id="q3">
        div 3
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```